# Convert GWT widget to Joomla module

Tags: gwt, joomla

Is there a way I can convert a GWT Widget to a joomla module or any way in general i can reuse the code from gwt to Joomla.?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Embedding a GWT widget in an HTML page should be pretty straightforward, it's just JS after all. If you're talking about code sharing, it won't be possible because Joomla is written in PHP, while GWT apps are written in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlikely, Joomla is a PHP-based, template-style CMS. GWT cross compiles Java to Javascript and provides a UI component library. They differ by both language and programming model.